# Are there any practical applications of the Kolakoski sequence $(1,3)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fixed-point-theorems

The most known Kolakoski sequence is defined on  the alphabet set $\{1,2\}$.
It is used as a fixed point of the run-length encoding operator.
But what about the sequence constructed on $\{1,3\}$. Are there any applications of this sequence ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the classical Kolakoski sequence on the alphabet $\{1,2\}$, it's analogue on $\{1,3\}$ can be related to a primitive substitution rule. Using this connection, it has been proven that the corresponding bi-infinite fixed point is a regular generic model set and thus having a pure point diffraction spectrum. The Kolakoski-$(3,1)$ sequence is then obtained as a deformation, without losing the pure point diffraction property.

---

I hope you can get the required information in [this paper by Baake and Sing](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0206098v2.pdf). Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually, after Google Search I haven't found any other result other than this on the Kolakoski {1,3} sequence.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time you took.

Comment: It is actually a deformed model set. And if I remember right, the same conclusion holds for Kolakoski (a,b) where $a,b$ are odd integers. The case where $(a,b)$ are even is also pretty well understood; the hard case is $a+b$ odd.